# How the graph in Attention is All you Need is drawn?

Tags: graph, neural-network, drawing

I want to draw pictures like this, any easy-to-use software of toolkits available?
[image]

I've tried TiKZ and I'm really confused to draw the such layer-behind-layer structure, any resources?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by using `scope`.

```tex
\begin{scope}[yshift=9.5cm,xshift=4.5cm]
        \coordinate(h1) at (0,0); 
        \node[row] (r1) [below =0.28 of h1] {};
        \node[circ1] (h11) [left=-0.47 of r1] {};
        \node[circ1] (h12) [right=0.07 of h11] {};
        \node[circ1] (h13) [right=0.07 of h12] {};
        \node[row] (r2) [above=0.05 of r1]{};
        \node[circ1] (h21) [above=0.17 of h11] {};
        \node[circ1] (h22) [above=0.17 of h12] {};
        \node[circ1] (h23) [above=0.17 of h13] {};
        \node[row] [above=0.05 of r2]{};
        \node[circ1] (h31) [above=0.17 of h21] {};
        \node[circ1] (h32) [above=0.17 of h22] {};
        \node[circ1] (h33) [above=0.17 of h23] {};
        \node[box] (his1) at (h1) {};

    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=9.4cm,xshift=4.4cm]
        \coordinate(h1) at (0,0);
        \fill[white,fill opacity=.8] (-0.8,-0.8) rectangle (0.8,0.8);
        
        \node[row] (r4) [above =1 of h1] {};
        \node[circ3] (h41) [left=-0.47 of r4] {};
        \node[circ3] (h42) [right=0.07 of h41] {};
        \node[circ3] (h43) [right=0.07 of h42] {};
        
        \node[row] (r1) [below =0.28 of h1] {};
        \node[circ1] (h11) [left=-0.47 of r1] {};
        \node[circ1] (h12) [right=0.07 of h11] {};
        \node[circ1] (h13) [right=0.07 of h12] {};
        \node[row] (r2) [above=0.05 of r1]{};
        \node[circ1] (h21) [above=0.17 of h11] {};
        \node[circ1] (h22) [above=0.17 of h12] {};
        \node[circ1] (h23) [above=0.17 of h13] {};
        \node[row] [above=0.05 of r2]{};
        \node[circ1] (h31) [above=0.17 of h21] {};
        \node[circ1] (h32) [above=0.17 of h22] {};
        \node[circ1] (h33) [above=0.17 of h23] {};
        \node[box] (his1) at (h1) {};
    \end{scope}
```